# Not able to change the location path

Tags: angularjs

Redirecting is not functional in the below code.  My `console.log()` works fine, but the URL doesn't change.  Needless to say, I'm confused as to why.  I've changed the URL like this is another section of my application and it works great.

```
angular.module('workstation.process.approval', [
        /* Dependencies */
        'workstation.services'
    ]).

    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        /* URL mappings */
        $routeProvider.
            when('/approval', {templateUrl: 'partials/loading.htm',   controller: 'ApprovalCtrl'}).
            when('/approval/dashboard', {templateUrl: 'partials/approval/dashboard.htm',   controller: 'ApprovalCtrl'})
    }]).

    controller('ApprovalCtrl', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', 'WorkflowProcessService', 'socketUrl', '$location', function ($scope, $cookieStore, WorkflowProcessService, socketUrl, $location) {
        var socket = portal.open(socketUrl+'/socket/workstation/approval');
        socket.on({
            open: function () {
                this.send('getDashboard', {
                    workstationUuid: $cookieStore.get('workstationUuid')
                }, function(r) {
                    $scope.dashboard = r;
                    console.log('swap-path', r);
                    $location.path('/approval/dashboard'); //NOT WORKING
                });
            },
            close: function (reason) {
                console.log(reason);
            }
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: Try adding `$scope.$apply()` after you change the path.  The socket `on` callback is called outside Angular, so you may need to tell Angular to run a digest cycle to notice the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding $scope.$apply() after you change the path. The socket on callback is called outside Angular, so you may need to tell Angular to run a digest cycle to notice the change. – Mark Rajcok May 14 at 21:18

it works for me thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think, window.location() would suit your needs.

Just add 
[$window](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24window) as a dependency

regards